# How can I get facebook user id along with email,name in the following method

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

How can I get facebook user id along with email,name in the following getProfileInformation(), here I would like to get the user id, and want to show in a toast message along with email and name in the run();

```
public void getProfileInformation() {
    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Profile", response);
            String json = response;
            try {
                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
                // getting name of the user
                final String name = profile.getString("name");
                // getting email of the user
                final String email = profile.getString("email"); 
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() { 
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the required fields in a Bundle in your request:

```
public void getProfileInformation() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "id,name,email");

    mAsyncRunner.request("me", params, new RequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        Log.d("Profile", response);
        String json = response;
        try {
            JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
            // getting name of the user
            final String name = profile.getString("name");
            // getting email of the user
            final String email = profile.getString("email"); 
            final Long id = profile.getLong("id");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() { 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID:" + id + "\nName: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
...
```

Note that you will require the "email" permission.

Comment: is it possible to get userid like email and name as shown in code?

Comment: Yes, you can access the id the same way you access name and email: Long id = profile.getLong("id");

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking, please clarify.

Comment: try {
                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
                // getting name of the user
                final String name = profile.getString("name");
                // getting email of the user
                final String email = profile.getString("email");

Comment: In this code i am getting email and name of user(who is login with facebook details in to my app)like that how can i get the user id ??

Comment: Just add what I wrote above (see also my edited answer).